# jQuery `.parent().remove()` is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

The solution may be obvious, but when clicking the `.remove` element, I am trying to remove the entire `.tag` element that is the parent. Currently, clicking the `.remove` element has no response.

**HTML**

```
'<div class="tag"><input id="' + id + '" type="hidden" name="' + name + '" value="' + value + '" />' + input + '<i class="remove dismiss fa fa-remove"></i></div>'
```

**JS**

```
$('.remove').on('click', '.remove', function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: Are your elements being added to the page dynamically?

Comment: Please post your question with proper format, as this html string looks like html code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this : As you are adding remove link dynamically, you need to register click handler using `.on()`. But in your case you have error in using `.on()`. Please use below code.

```
$(document).on('click', '.remove', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

More Information on **[jQuery .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**

Comment: "As you are adding remove link dynamically" How do you know this?

Comment: in html OP using `id="'+id+'"` and  `+input+` hence it is dynamic. Though OP need to format the post properly.

Comment: who is OP? I can understand DD but OP?

Comment: @man_luck OP is actullay Original Poster. This is used to refer the person who has asked the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/myyzrwwe/

```
$('.remove').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't always use delegate the event to the same element that has been delegated. You need to select a static **parent**. In my example, the `document` object is **the** parent of everything.

```
$('body').on('click', '.remove', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be you are binding the event to .remove, if this content is dynamic you might have a problem. Its better, in those cases, to bind to document.

```
$(document).on()
```

The callback has the event parameter, use that to remove.

```
function(e) {
  $(e.currentTarget).parent().remove();
}
```

Check if you undelegate elements.